# xpath for random generated element id

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am facing an issue to locate xpath of a row which has element id's that are randomly generated.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a slotId=2>1996</a>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <td><strong>No data to display></strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <table id=ct164_Name>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span class=Name><input id=text_ct164_name><label id=label_ct164_name>Smith</label></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id=text_ct164_Amount class=myamount>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea id=area_ct164_comments class=Mycomments>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a id=button_ct164_Status class=2 status available></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a slotId=3>1997</a>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <td><strong>No data to display></strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <table id=ct165_Name>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span class=Name><input id=text_ct165_name><label id=label_ct165_name>Carters</label></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id=text_ct165_Amount class=myamount>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea id=area_ct165_comments class=Mycomments>
                        </td>
                        <td><a id=button_ct165_Status class=My status>2 status available</a></td>
                </tr>
    ....
    ....
    ....            
</table>
```

I am able to get find the element which has year in it by xpath.
`//table[contains(@id,"main_uxSlots")][@class="grid"]//tr//td//a[.="1996"]`

Now, I want to fetch all elements in the row where year is 1996. `SlotID` and `ct` values are generated dynamically so I can't hard code them.

There are about 100-200 rows in the table with same class and similar text values except year. Can someone please suggest a way to tackle this situation and get `ct` value based on year. Once i get `ct` value, i can fetch id of all elements I want to access.

Comment: Can you please update the `HTML` as formatted text for a quick analysis?

Comment: What exactly are you referring as `ct` values? `table id`, `input id`, `label id`, `textarea id`, `a id` all have values with `ct`.

Comment: Yes, all has `ct` values in their id which is why I want to capture ct value once so that i can use it to fetch other elements.

Comment: for example. id of textarea is `area_ct164_comments' and id of input is `text_ct165_Amount` for first row and second row has `ct165`, 3rd row as `ct166`, etc.. I want to capture `ct` value of the row where text is 1996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issue in your HTML Code:

- missed close tag for A, TEATAREA;
- TR appeared in wrong place

please give a correct and well-formated HTML Code, We need the exact relationship of related elements to find your wanted element.

I did a roughly guess on the correct HTML code and give below code to resolve your problem:

```
var util = require('util');

function getId(year) {
    var xpathPattern = '//table[contains(@id, "main_uxSlots")][@class="grid"]' + 
        '/tbody/tr[td/a[.="%s"]]//table';

    var xpathExp = util.format(xpathPattern, year);

    return element(by.xpath(xpathExp))
        .getAttribute('id')
        .then(function(id){
            return id.split('_')[0];
        });
}

function readAmount(year) {

    return getId(year).then(function(id){
        var cssExp = util.format('input#text_%s_Amount', id);

        return element(by.css(cssExp)).getAttribute('value');
    });
}

function readComments(year) {

    return getId(year).then(function(id){
        var cssExp = util.format('textarea#area_%s_comments', id);

        return element(by.css(cssExp)).getAttribute('value');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yong. This approach worked for to fetch id of the element.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like all the years is going to be a link. So why not go upwards.

```
//a[.="1996"]/../..
```

This xpath will give you all the rows which has year 1996. Now just iterate though this rows for any sepecific elements you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this but problem is I am unable to differentiate input and textarea from the rows.